# API design for Java String results which contain charset-specific data

Tags: java, html, string, encoding, api-design

In the API of a document converter, which generates HTML (or XHTML), I want to expose these methods:

```
// Convert the input file to a file using the specified charset
void convert(File in, File out, Charset charset);

// Convert the input document to a string using the specified charset
String convert(String in, Charset charset);
```

There is no way for client code to produce faulty documents with the file-based method, it safely writes a result document with the specified charset.

The String based method obviuously will lead to problems, if the client code does not respect the chosen charset - for example if the charset parameter is ISO-8859-1 but the result String is served as UTF-8 content in a web application:

```
String html = convert(getInputDocument(), ISO_8859_1);
...
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
  out.print(html);
}
```

Question: which options should I consider to design the API so that users are guided to correct usage of the result string?

- deprecate the method and provide a method which returns a byte array
- use method names which contain the encoding (convertToUTF_8, convertToISO_8859_1 ...)

---

The result string could for example be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Untitled document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Mot&ouml;rhead</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact use-case, but one possibility is to protect document with a proper object context (instead of it just being a `String`):

```java
public interface Document {
    void writeTo(ServletResponse response);
}
```

This way you can retain all control of how that "string" can be written to different targets.

I'm not sure whether you need a `convert` at all, since the document could automatically convert its content if it sees that the response already has a different encoding. But even if you need a `convert` you could do it this way:

```java
public interface Document {
    void writeTo(ServletResponse response);

    Document convert(Charset targetCharset);
}
```

This would return a new document which is of a different charset.